# Lowercase first letter and use "_" instead of " " in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a Java programm and I would like to make every character of a word in a String a lowercase character and replace an empty space " " by a "_". So here are some expample:

- "Tall Building" --> "tall_building"
- "Red Shoes" --> "red_shoes"
- "Water" --> "water"

I do not want to use any libarary if that is possible. Would you mind telling me how I can do that? I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: `str.replace(" ", "_").toLowerCase()` or `str.replaceAll("\\s+", "_").toLowerCase()`

Comment: Did you try anything yourself, have you looked at the documentation for the `String` class to see if there is something you can use?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I tried something on my own but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String modifyString(String str) {
    if (str == null)
        return null;
    if (str.isEmpty())
        return str;
    
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(str.length());
    
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        buf.append(ch == ' ' ? '_' : Character.toLowerCase(ch));
    }
    
    return buf.toString();
}
```

***P.S.** Sure it could be more another solutions e.g. like `str.replace(" ", "_").toLowerCase()`. My solution uses `StringBuilder` which is correct way buil `String` and does not use `Regexp`. Time complexity is `O(n)`.*

Comment: Thanks oleg for your answer. When I use it I get the error message "Cannot resolve method 'chatAt' in 'String'". Do I need any external library for that?

Comment: `str.charAt(i)` - typo!

Comment: Ah okay, thanks Oleg for your help :-)